# Controled prop name in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I'm stuck with a TypeScript typing problem and can't find anything related.

I'm trying to add dynamic slots to my components, and want props' name to be a specific template including any string, a number and the 'Slot' string (i.e. custom3Slot).

What I'd like to achieve is to declare this type of props like this in my component's props TS declaration:

```
[key: SlotName]: ReactElement;
```

For now, SlotName is declared like this :

```
type SlotName = `${string}${number}Slot`;
```

The problem is the first string can only take one character. So "c3Slot" is valid, but "cu3Slot" or "custom3Slot" are not. I can't find a way to make this first string being of any length.

Complete exmaple ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoUWAogGwgWwnGQG9kB6c5AZzDhABMBaUAKGQ+TAE8AHCAFw0wUUAHMA3KwC+rVj37IAyjgD2YAHJxCyALzIABgBIStUSDHSTIAK74ARtGkr1Bqa1CRYiFABUAFhAAkuDQ8Eik7JwA2gDWENxCLpraEAC6QuiYuAREYBLIMnIIqiC0yAAeQgHBod4R+iRRHAgAzMlCJAqCyABEcL3SADTNyAg27Wpgnd1CvfaDI9JSQA)):

```typescript
type SlotName = `${string}${number}Slot`;

interface TheInterface {
    [key: SlotName]: ReactElement; 
}

const x: TheInterface = {
    c3Slot:  /*...*/,
    cu3Slot: /*...*/, // Error: Object literal may only specify known
                      // properties, and 'cu3Slot' does not exist in type
                      // 'TheInterface'. (2322)
};
```

Comment: What counts as a "number" for you?  Keep in mind that `"1.23e+45"` and `"0xDEADBEEF"` are both  `\`${number}\``s.  Is that okay?

Comment: If you really want something like `/^[a-zA-Z]+(0|([1-9][0-9]*))Slot$/` (that is, one or more alpha characters followed by a non-negative whole number, followed by "Slot"), then there is no specific type in TypeScript that will represent this exactly.  You can write a *constraint* though, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yvAw).  If that meets your needs I can write it up (although it's kind of crazy); otherwise maybe the `\`${string}${string}${number}\`` answer will work for you?

Comment: [Similar approach, still crazy](https://tsplay.dev/NaYXoN)

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, `${string}${number}` just means "a single character followed by a number" even though `${string}` on its own (without another placeholder after it) would allow multiple characters. There's a [feature suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42903) to...update...that behavior (originally a bug report), but it was marked "working as intended" by the language creator and closed.

Until/unless they do that, you can define `SlotName` as a union of a bunch of patterns to allow multiple characters:

```typescript
type SlotName = 
    `${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot` |
    `${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${string}${number}Slot`;
```

That allows:

```typescript
const x: TheInterface = {
    c3Slot: {type: "a"},
    cu3Slot: {type: "b"},
    cxx3Slot: {type: "c"},
    cxxx3Slot: {type: "d"},
    cxxxx3Slot: {type: "e"},
    cxxxxx3Slot: {type: "f"},
    cxxxxxx3Slot: {type: "g"},
    cxxxxxxx3Slot: {type: "h"},
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#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)

Not ideal, but it works. Keep going for as many characters as you need.

(Perhaps someone better at TypeScript than I am can point out how to use a recursive or mapped type for it.)

Comment: I tested your solution in the questions code (`TheInterface`) and it didn't produce errors for slots that had more than 8 letters (using your pattern above).

Comment: @Inigo - Can you share a playground for that? When [I tried it](https://tsplay.dev/mLLGem), it did give an error when the prefix was too long for the unions that made up `SlotName` (and then [not](https://tsplay.dev/w14YOW) if I added another union member to cover it). Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: So it looks like for TS 4.3 and earlier it doesn't work... You can see that in your original playground. I had tested it in a scratch file in my IDE where I had TS 4.2 going.

Comment: @Inigo - Right -- the feature the OP is using was [added in v4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures).

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WYBDdw) is a recursive type for it, if it matters.  It is weird to use `\`${string}${string}${string}${number}\`` this way, even though it's working as intended.  Personally I have an issue with `\`${number}\`` since it doesn't mean what people think it means (e.g, `"0xF"` is accepted), but there's no specific object type corresponding to what the OP actually wants, so maybe this is good enough?

Comment: @jcalz - WOW, that's really cool. And yeah, it's tempting to use a `digit` union in the same way instead of `number`...

Comment: Even the `string` part is not great, since `"58ronfc9K(*@%@FWS13298GF% d492kd94Slot"` will also work since `string` doesn't mean `alpha`.  If you try to use digit unions or alpha unions then you'll run into union size limits after a few characters and/or five digits

Comment: @jcalz - yeah, I'm familar with what `string` and `number` mean, but as you say, we have few really good options. :-)