# Typescript - type to check if the string contains only specific characters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to have type check for strings that we know will contains only certain values.
Example: `const binary = '1010000101000';` We know that binary values represented in decimal would only be 1's & 0's. To have a better type check, what would be a good type definition for these kinds of values.

`type Binary = '0' | '1';` wouldn't work, because these would be representing only single characters of the string. But the idea is how to have an interface/type for the whole string that we know would contain only certain types of characters in a string.

The question is **not about choosing interface for binary values**, it's how to declare/define types for predefined string values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Controled prop name in TypeScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447567/controled-prop-name-in-typescript)

Comment: Applying the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447567/controled-prop-name-in-typescript)'s answer to this: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoadlN). Ugly and limited (you can't go longer than shown there), but I don't think the type system gives you a better way to do this.

Comment: Adding type checking this way will be more tedious than it bring the benefits. It would be better that I add a regex check

Comment: In this case, yup. :-)

Comment: fyi there is no compile time regex check (yet) : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160 ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive typing :

```
type BinDigit = "0" | "1"

type OnlyBinDigit<S> =
    S extends ""
        ? unknown
        : S extends `${BinDigit}${infer Tail}`
            ? OnlyBinDigit<Tail>
            : never




function onlyBinDigit<S extends string>(s: S & OnlyBinDigit<S>) {
}



onlyBinDigit("01010101010011"); // OK 
onlyBinDigit("010101012"); // NOK
```

To explain a bit the typing here, `OnlyBinDigit` is recursive type.

- Base case : empty string returns the type `unknown`.
- Recurcivity : using template literals we can split the string and make a recursive call on the tail until we reach the empty string.
- In non-recursive part the template literal, if the first character doesn't match the type (here `'0' | '1'`), it will return `never` thus failing the typecheck.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgOwCJwOZ2FAvFARABlygB88BGXAWACgbRIoB5BAGxHmTQwB4BlAPmw0oIqLygQAHsAgIAJgGc8VaqLVQA-FACuCANYIA9gHcEw9SIBcYidNmKoAAwAkAbw4p0wAL5vEAMwgAJygAFQBDOBZvR3MLNS1mNg8uYG4IqP44%20KsoBAgAN2CaEtoy-10AY2A4QwQoOuTETx5xKRl5JQVgIMRUfgAKBWtxADImVnZm1L5%20AEooVxpvUtLGqc4vAYIyfF39vfw9ijmAbigAegumAGkoGnWUrZ3D-YAmXDPL64A5RhvVtQgA)

Comment: This works perfectly, could you explain what is happening here.